# In Symfony2 -> Twig, how to detect if the execution is from CLI mode or through browser?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am making a Symfony2 console command that will send a e-mail rendering a Twig template.
The e-mail template uses some standard layout that is also included in the e-mails sent from browser requests.
In this template i have some links like this:

```
{{ url('deal_category_index', {'city':app.session.get('system.user.city'), 'slug':cat.getSlug()}) }}
```

But if i use the `app.session` in CLI mode, i get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").")
```

So i need a way to know if the template is rendered from CLI so i can use a "generic" way to create this link.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Extract the city from the session in the controller and pass it to the render() function. This way, your template should look like:

```
{{ url('deal_category_index', {'city': city, 'slug':cat.getSlug()}) }}
```

And in your controller:

```
$this->render("YourBundle:Yourcontroller:yourView.html.twig', array('city' => $this->get('session')->get('system.user.city'), 'cat' => $category);
```

When calling the render() in CLI, you should grab the city from database instead of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the layout part depending on the request context in a block:

```
{% block foobar_url %}
  {{ url('deal_category_index', {'city':app.session.get('system.user.city')}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Use this layout in the emails sent from browser context just as you did before.

Override the code block `foobar_url` in your CLI templates like so:

```
{% block foobar_url %}
  {{ url('deal_category_index', {'city':cityRetrievedFromDatabaseOrElsewhere}) }}
{% endblock %}
```